# How to implement some of these Ruby concepts?

Tags: ruby, oop

1. In order to call `MyClass::empty().empty`
    Do I need to implement an empty method in side MyClass? What would I write inside it?
2. Following, I am not sure how such a call could work: `x = MyClass::empty().add("a").add("b")`
   Would this be simply calling the add method if it is empty?

Comment: What would `MyClass::empty().empty` return? And why not simply `MyClass::empty()`?

Comment: I am just learning Ruby and following some examples that I could find from back when I took a Ruby class. MyClass::empty().empty would return true or false. I am not sure why .empty instead of just empty, but isn't that just a matter of whether that method returns something or whether you are accessing its property?

Comment: what type would empty() return?

Comment: Boolean - true or false - see above

Comment: @antonpug No. `empty()` returns an instance of an object with an `empty` method. *That* `empty` could return true/false. `MyClass::empty()` cannot, because then you couldn't call `add` on it, unless it's very pathological, non-obvious, and non-communicative.

Comment: @antonpug: There are no _properties_ in Ruby. Only methods. Object attributes (which are always private) are accessed through methods as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would you write inside it? What do you want it to do?

You'd have a class method named `empty` that returns something having an `empty` method that either (a) took no parameters, or (b) had them defaulted.

```
class MyClass
  def self.empty
    return WithEmpty.new # Or existing WithEmpty
  end
end
```

It also needs to return something that has an `add` method, and returns itself.

```
class WithEmpty
  def initialize
    @a_list = []
  end

  def add x
    @a_list << x
    self
  end

  def empty
    @a_list.empty?
  end
end
```

It'd be easier/quicker if you described what you're trying to do. It's not immediately obvious.

```
pry(main)> MyClass::empty()
=> #<WithEmpty:0xa01a090 @a_list=[]>
pry(main)> MyClass::empty().empty
=> true
pry(main)> MyClass::empty.empty
=> true
pry(main)> MyClass::empty.add("hi").add("bye")
=> #<WithEmpty:0x9fc8d1c @a_list=["hi", "bye"]>
```

Now you have no immediate way to get to the "inner" class's list, unless you saved it in either `MyClass` (sketchy, since the methods are class, not instance, method), or you save the return value from the last bunch of chained methods.

But if you save the instance, what's the point of doing it through `MyClass`? Again, I can't help but think you need to define what you're actually trying to accomplish, rather than focusing on how you might accomplish it. What's the goal?

---

Firstly, there is no "add" method for an array. What you're describing, as yet, makes no sense, unless you mean something like this:

```
class MyClass
  def self.empty
    return MyClass.new
  end

  def initialize
    @arr = []
  end

  def empty
    @arr.empty?
  end

  def add x
    @arr << x
    self
  end
end
```

Then:

```
pry(main)> MyClass.empty
=> #<MyClass:0x9aea390 @arr=[]>
pry(main)> MyClass.empty.add("ohai").add("kthxbai")
=> #<MyClass:0x99f505c @arr=["ohai", "kthxbai"]>
```

But again: you're mixing class and instance methods in a way I don't find sensical. How do you want to access the array? What's the point of `MyClass`? Why not just use an array?

```
pry(main)> a = []
=> []
pry(main)> a.empty?
=> true
pry(main)> a << "ohai" << "kthxbai"
=> ["ohai", "kthxbai"]
pry(main)> 
pry(main)> a.empty?
=> false
```

Without any guidelines for what `MyClass`'s purpose is, telling you a reasonable way to implement it is difficult, because without context, what you've shown doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: 1. What is WithEmpty? I have an array which I want to check if it is empty, I don't think that would be checking it? 2. Here what I am trying to do is to add items to an array. I am following some old class material from a few years back and for some reason it uses ::empty().add(---).add(---).add(---) format.

Comment: You check an array for emptiness by called `empty?` on it. See update.

Comment: Yes. And there isn't really a "goal" I am just trying to learn Ruby. Following some really old class examples from when I took the class.

Comment: "Yes" what? My question regarding a goal wasn't about like your life ambitions or anything, rather "what do you want the semantics of `MyClass` to be?" Without knowing the purpose of `MyClass`, how to write it in a way that makes sense will remain elusive.

Comment: It should basically maintain a sequence of numbers, nothing complex. I am not quite sure why the example I am trying to follow uses this weird way

Comment: @antonpug, looks like you are using learning materials that confuse you. Maybe you should learn ruby by reading better materials, like documents available here: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ 
Regarding your question, as Dave Newton said in this answer, you just need to use an Array from base ruby library.